# TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment in a nested python list

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror

```
import pprint
train_data = [[1,1,1], [1,2,2], [2,1,3], [2,2,2],[3,1,1], [3,2,2], [4,1,3], [4,2,2]]
train_label = [[1], [1], [2], [2]]
```

This is the data, basically I am trying to solve a Text Classification Problem. `train_data` is formatted as `[[docID, wordID, count]` and `train_label` determines which document ID belongs to which class. So in the given case, document at position 1 belongs to class 1 and document at position 3 belongs to class2.

```
totaldata = []
```

In total data column 1 is document ID, column 2 is wordID and column3 is it's count.

```
 for index in range(len(train_data)):
        temp =[]
        if index == 0:
            temp.append(train_label[train_data[index][0]-1][0])
            temp.append(train_data[index][0])
            temp.append(train_data[index][1])
            temp.append(train_data[index][2])
            totaldata.append(temp)
        elif(totaldata[len(totaldata)-1][0] == train_label[train_data[index][0] -1][0]):
            temp.append(train_label[train_data[index][0] -1 ][0])
            temp.append(train_data[index][0])
            temp.append(train_data[index][1])
            temp.append(train_data[index][2])
            totaldata.append(temp)
        elif(totaldata[len(totaldata)-1][0] != train_label[train_data[index][0] -1][0]):
            temp.append(train_label[train_data[index][0] -1 ][0])
            temp.append(train_data[index][0])
            temp.append(train_data[index][1])
            temp.append(train_data[index][2])
            totaldata.append(temp)
```

`TotalData` is a nested list which combines data from previous two lists and gives an output in the form of `[[classID, docID, wordID, Count]]`

```
    nf = []
```

In `nf` I want to store the total count of a specific wordID in a specific class.

That means my expected output should be `[[1,1,4],[1,2,4],[2,1,4],[2,2,4]]`

```
nf = []
for index in range(len(totaldata)):
    for i in range(len(totaldata)):
        temp = []
        temp.append(totaldata[index][0])
        if i == 0:
            sum = totaldata[index][3]
            temp.append(totaldata[index][2])
            temp.append(sum)
            nf.append(temp)
        elif(((nf[-1][0]) ==totaldata[i][0])and nf[-1][1] == totaldata[i][2]):
            sum+= totaldata[i][3]
            nf[-1][2] = sum
        elif(((nf[-1][0]) ==totaldata[i][0])and nf[-1][1] != totaldata[i][2]):
            sum = int(totaldata[i][3])
            temp.append(totaldata[i][2])
            temp.append(sum)
            nf.append(sum) 

pprint.pprint(nf)
```

Comment: we need far more information on what your input are, what your output should be, what your code is doing. Basically a [MCVE]

Comment: `nf` is a one-dimensional list, containing just ints. But in that line you are trying to access `nf[x][3]` - why?

Comment: If you want the last item in a list, just do `mylist[-1]`.

Comment: @MooingRawr I have updated the question to respond to all your questions.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks for telling me this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch this elif statement.

```
elif(((totaldata[len(totaldata)-1][0]) ==totaldata[index][0])and totaldata[len(totaldata)-1][0] != totaldata[index][2]):
    sum = int(totaldata[index][3])
    temp.append(totaldata[index][0])
    temp.append(totaldata[index][2])
    temp.append(sum)
    nf.append(sum)
```

You are appending an integer to `nf` (the `sum` variable you calculated earlier), guess that final line should be

```
    nf.append(temp)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. This was the mistake I was doing. But I still got the logic wrong. I would appreciate if you could help me with that as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
nf[len(nf) -1][3] = sum
```

`nf` is a single list of integers, but you're trying to treat it like a two-dimensional list.